# How to save learned weights/parameters of PCA and T-SNE in Sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have two set of data let's say A and B.
I want to apply PCA and T-sne to A and fine tune the algo.
Once, I am satisfied with my tuning I want to save the learnt things to some pickle file.
Now I want to apply the same learnt PCA and t-sne to set B.
I want t-sne to produce the same results every time on B. I am hoping this because I am assuming, we can save the state of learnt t-sne parametes also. If the parametes are same, and when I load the same file everytime, the result of applying t-sne on the set B should be same every time.
How can I do this in Sklearn and python?
I am sorry, I am new to ML and python, this may be a very basic question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fine-tuning T-SNE equals tuning some heuristic-algorithm (it's ill-conditioned after all; higher-dimension -> lower-dimension mapping is lossy) for your data.

Applying this tuned & learned mapping to other data is done by sklearn's `transform`.

**But**: you will see that there is no `transform`-method for T-SNE and the reason is given [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5361) (including further discussion):

> It is a transductive learner, like many clustering algorithms: the model is not really applicable beyond the data points it is fed as training.

So whatever you tuned for dataset A, does not really apply to dataset B (including parameters)!

For PCA this is trivial. Use the methods described in [docs: model_persistence](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) and use PCA's [transform](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.transform)-method (assuming compatible datasets; dimensions!).

Answer (score -2):

To be able to save the models you should use the below library:

```
from joblib import dump, load
```

after establishing the model as below in PCA:

```
pca_model = PCA(n_components=n)
```

you can save the model in joblib format in the current directory:

```
dump(pca_model, 'pca_model.joblib')
```

Comment: This does not save the *fitted* model, as clearly requested by the OP. And importing the `load` method without actually using it in the answer is at least puzzling.

Comment: You should run a pca_model .fit(X_yourtraindata)  before saving the model, I believe that's the reason of the downvotes.